# QT OpenGl не инициализируется

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

Хочу запустить и посмотреть код с этого урока
https://www.bogotobogo.com/Qt/Qt5_OpenGL_QGLWidget.php
Но мешают ошибки такого вида. В чём может быть проблема и как её исправить?
QT 5.12.5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: QT+=opengl в проект нужно добавить.

Comment: там уже есть
QT       += core gui opengl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В случае когда в Qt5 используется OpenGL версии 1, то есть glBegin/glEnd и т.п. необходимо библиотеку OpenGL указывать в проекте. Добавьте в проект:

```
LIBS += -lopengl32
```